# Trouble accessing my web site

Tags: website

Hi I was wondering if anyone could help..... 
I have a web site [www.spotondrivingschool.co.uk](http://www.spotondrivingschool.co.uk)  when  myself, or anyone for that matter tries to access it, it is now displaying a message saying it cannot be found. I have no idea why this is. Can anyone help. Please x

Comment: did you mean www.spotondrivingschool.co.uk?  .c.uk doesn't exist.

Comment: yes sorry, www.spotondrivingschool.co.uk

Comment: Speak to your web hosting company. Whois Record ( last updated on 2015-06-18 ) which is yesterday so something has changed (I'm not sure what)

Comment: By the way your name and address are exposed on the registration. Not usually a good idea :/

Comment: Thanks David, i wasnt aware my name and address was on it. Like i say, i just left him to do it :(

Answer (score 1):

Initial tests shows everything is valid, up until the web-server itself.  (DNS resolves, server responds to HTTP requests, etc...) the web-server probably doesn't have the proper virtualhost configuration, or has some error running some scripts of some sort.  Check the config and logs.

Comment: Alternatively, contact your hosting provider; the hosting provider appears to be Filoo.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. I have just noticed that this page says it is for computer enthusiasts and power users. I am going to be totally honest with you, hence why i was looking for help,  I have very little knowledge of computers etc. A friend of a friend set me up a web site roughly 2 years ago, and so far i have had no problems. It has been brought to my attention today that this message was  being displayed. So although I have no idea what your reply meant, I thank you anyway for trying to help :-(